# Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $n \times n$ matrix where $a_{ij} = \max(i,j)$. Find the determinant of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $n \times n$ matrix where $a_{ij} = \max(i,j)$. Find the determinant of $A$. How to find the solution of this kind of problem?

Comment: Similar problem with $\min$ instead of $\max$ can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392738/evaluation-of-a-specific-determinant/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2013663/321264

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $2\le k\le n$ substract the $k$-th row from the $k-1$-row.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on what Not Me's answer.

If you subtract row 1 from row 2, row 2 from row 3 etc you get
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&3&\cdots& n\\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots&\vdots & \ddots & 1
}
$$
If you expand on the first row, you see that the determinant is $\pm n$ with $+$ if $n$ is odd and $-$ if $n$ is even. So the final answer is 
$$
\text{Determinant} = (-1)^{n-1} n = - (-1)^n n$$

Comment: if $n=2$ $\det = -2$, and if $n=3$ $\det = -3$. Why do you have $1$ in the right down corner ?

Answer (score -1):

Subtract the 1st row from the 2nd row we have the new 2nd row to be :

1 0 0 ... 0.
Expand the determinant on this 2nd row we have it equal to:

-1*/A/ where A is the new minor of the form:

2 3 4 5 ... n

3 3 4 5.... n

4 4 4 5 ... n

Repeat step 1 by subtracting 1st row of A from 2nd row of A and expand along the 2nd row we get:

1*/B/ with B is the minor of A by deleting the 2nd row and 2nd column of A. Repeating this step on the way to the last step that we have: the final minor to be:

(n - 1)   n

n      n

this one has determinant = n(n - 1) - n*n  = -n. So the final answer is: -n if n = even, and n if n = odd.

Comment: The determinant is not always negative. Try with $n=3$.

Comment: n = 3 det(A) = - 3.

Comment: yes, plus or minus .

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear from your answer if the determinant is positive or negative. So... how do we decide? ;)

Comment: I just fixed it in the calculation.

Comment: If $n$ is even, the determinant is negative.

Comment: it is now fixed.