# If $a_{ij}=\max(i,j)$, calculate the determinant of $A$

Tags: matrices, determinant

> If $A$ is an $n \times n$ real matrix and
>
> $$a_{ij}=\max(i,j)$$
>
> for $i,j = 1,2,\dots,n$, calculate the determinant of $A$.

So, we know that

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n\\ 
2 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n\\ 
3 & 3 & 3 & \dots & n\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
 n& n & n & \dots & n
\end{pmatrix}$$

but what do I do after?

Comment: I'd say, subtract the second column from the first, and then use the first column to eliminate the first row. Then do it again on the remaining $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ principal minor. Should become something like $(-1)^{n-1}n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d_n$ be the determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix

We can also write it as a recurrence

By expanding on the last row (or column) we observe that all but the minors of last two columns have linear dependent columns, so we have:

$d_n=-\frac{n^2}{n-1}d_{n-1}+nd_{n-1}=-\frac{n}{n-1}d_{n-1}$

Coupled with $d_1=1$ we get $d_n=(-1)^{n-1}n$

Comment: What does it mean linear dependent columns?

Comment: It means that you can find two numbers say $a$ and $b$ such as $a\cdot\text{first column}+b\cdot\text{second column}=0$. If this happens, then your minor is $0$

Comment: In your case, except for the last two minors, the rest of the minors have the columns \begin{pmatrix}
n-1 \\ 
n-1 \\ 
 \vdots \\ 
 n-1
\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix}
n \\ 
n \\ 
 \vdots \\ 
 n
\end{pmatrix} that can be made zero by multiplying the last column with $\frac{n-1}{n}$ and adding it to the last one.

Comment: Ok so i expanded after the last column. What should I do now?

Comment: Do you see why the first minor is zero?

Comment: Linear dependent columns does not mean that let's say L1=pL2+qL3, where p and q are some numbers?

Comment: that is also a linear dependence, but between three columns.

Comment: I do not understand how to show that it is 0. On the first minor I have on the last row n n n...n-1 and on the last column n-1 n-1... n-1

Comment: You look at the last two rows of the minors. Can they be made zero?

Comment: the last row is n n ... n. I suggest you to work on the 3x3 or 4x4 case first.

Comment: Oh yeah, right. Sorry I was wrong. Ok so we have on n-1 n-1 n-1... n-1 and n n n ..n so we can multiply the first with -n/n-1 and add it to the last.

Comment: If we look at the last minor we can say it is n*$d_{n-1}$ but what should I do with the other one?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the idea. So all are zero except for the last two of them. The last two can be written in terms of $d_{n-1}$ by using the property of the determinant that if one row/column is multiplied by a number, then the whole determinant multiplies by that number.

Comment: Ok so we have $nd_{n-1} + (-n)*the second to last minor$. What can I do with that one?

Comment: I think the second to last minor is the determinant of $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n-2&n\\ 
2 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n-2&n\\ 
3 & 3 & 3 & \dots & n-2&n\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots&\vdots\\ 
 n-1& n-1 & n-1 & \dots & n-1&n
\end{pmatrix}$$ which is $\frac{n}{n-1}$ times that of $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n-1\\ 
2 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n-1\\ 
3 & 3 & 3 & \dots & n-1\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
 n-1& n-1 & n-1 & \dots & n-1
\end{pmatrix},$$ i.e. $\frac{n}{n-1}d_{n-1}$.

Comment: Don't we have on the last rows n-2 n-2 n-2...n-1 and n n n...n?

Comment: Eh, sorry, I was expanding after the last row. Just transpose the two matrices then.

Comment: Cause for obtaining the second to last minor if you expand after the last column, you will cut the second to last row and last column.

Comment: Ok and why it is n/n-1. I mean can you do some operations other than observing it?

Comment: Because $\begin{pmatrix}
n\\
\vdots\\
 n
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{n}{n-1}\times\begin{pmatrix}
n-1\\
\vdots\\
 n-1
\end{pmatrix}$ and the determinant of the matrix with a row (or column) multiplied by $c$ is $c$ times the original determinant.

Comment: Ok I think I got this. Thanks.

Comment: It is my pleasure to help. BTW, this approach is really great, but the formula should be $$d_n=-\frac{n}{n-1}\times d_{n-1}.$$ :)

Comment: @awllower Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Hint to a more artsy proof:

Whenever $\mathcal{A}$ is a logical statement, we shall write $\left[\mathcal{A}\right]$ for the integer $\begin{cases} 1, & \text{ if } \mathcal{A} \text{ is true}; \\ 0, & \text{ if } \mathcal{A} \text{ is false} \end{cases}$. (This is called the Iverson bracket notation.)

Let $B$ be the $n\times n$-matrix whose $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry is $n \left[j=n\right] - \left[i \leq j < n\right]$. Here is how $B$ looks like:
$$
B = \left( \begin{array}{ccccc} -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 & n \\ 0 & -1 & \cdots & -1 & n \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & n \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n \end{array} \right) .
$$
The matrix $B$ is upper-triangular, and so $\det B = n \left(-1\right)^{n-1}$.

Let $C$ be the $n \times n$-matrix whose $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry is $\left[i \geq j\right]$. Here is how $C$ looks like:
$$
C = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right) .
$$
The matrix $C$ is lower-triangular, and so $\det C = 1$.

Now, check that $A = BC$, and conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Use row operation to transform it to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & ... &n \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & ... &0 \\ 
3 & 3 & 3 & ... & n\\ 
 ...&...  &...  &...  &... \\ 
 n& n & n & n & n
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then to (determinant is multiplied by $-1$)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & ... &0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 3 & ... &n \\ 
0 & 3 & 3 & ... & n\\ 
 ...&...  &...  &...  &... \\ 
 0& n & n & n & n
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and repeat the process.

Thus the determinant should be $(-1)^{n-1}n$.

Hope this helps.

---

It turns out this is just a reformulation of @G.Sassatelli's comment. Maybe I should delete it?

Comment: I think you can leave it here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By induction on $n$. Subtract row $n-1$ from $n$, row $n-2$ from $n-3$ and so on. Then expand by cofactors along the last column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do $L_i-L_{i+1}$ which would give you a triangular matrix and the determinant is only the product of the coefficients of the diagonal

Answer (score 0):

Apply row operations $R_{j} \leftarrow R_{j} - R_{1}, \, \forall j \in \left \{2, ...n\right \}$ on $A$ to get the following matrix:

$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 2 & 3 & ... & n-1 & n\\ 
 1&  0& 0 & ... &  0& 0\\ 
 2&  1& 0 & ... &  0& 0\\ 
 ...&  ...& ... & ... &  ...& ...\\ 
 n-2& n-3 & n-4 &  ...&  0& 0\\ 
 n-1&  n-2&  n-3&  ...&  1& 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Now, apply the following row operations in the order of $j = 2,3,...,n-1$,

$R_{k} \leftarrow R_{k} - (k-1)R_{j}, \, \forall k \in \left \{j+1, j+2, ..., n\right \}$

to get the following matrix:

$A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 2 & 3 & ... & n-1 & n\\ 
 1&  0& 0 & ... &  0& 0\\ 
 0&  1& 0 & ... &  0& 0\\ 
 ...&  ...& ... & ... &  ...& ...\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 &  ...&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  ...&  1& 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Now apply the following row operations $R_1 \leftarrow (j-1)R_j, \, \forall j \in {2,3,...,n}$ to get the following matrix:

$A_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
 0& 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & n\\ 
 1&  0& 0 & ... &  0& 0\\ 
 0&  1& 0 & ... &  0& 0\\ 
 ...&  ...& ... & ... &  ...& ...\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 &  ...&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  ...&  1& 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Note that $A_3$ has a value of $n$ at $(1,n)$th cell, all $1$s on the first lower off-diagonal and all other elements are $0$s. Now, compute the determinant along the first row to get:

$|A_3| = (-1)^{n+1}n$

Since, all the above row operations do not change the value of the determinant, we obtain,

$|A| = |A_1| = |A_2| = |A_3| = (-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: So as I saw from others the answer should be $(-1)^{n-1}n$.

Comment: $(-1)^{n+1}n$ is same as $(-1)^{n-1}n$. Using laplace formula for the computation of determinant in last step will lead to $$(-1)^{n+1}n$. Here, is the [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix) to laplace formula for the computation of determinant.

Comment: $(-1)^{n+1}n$ is same as $(-1)^{n-1}n$. Using Laplace formula for the computation of determinant in last step will lead to $(-1)^{n+1}n$. Here is the [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix) to Laplace formula for the computation of determinant.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can prove this using induction too. The n = $1$ case is trivial. Let, $\det(A_{n}) = n(-1)^{n-1}$. We'll need to prove $$\det(A_{n+1}) = (-1)^{n}(n+1)$$Now $A_{n+1}$ looks like:-
$$A_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}A_{n}&P\\
        P^{T}&n+1
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $P^{T} = (n+1)(1,1,...1)^{T}$ $$\det(A_{n+1}) = \det(A_{n} - P\frac{1}{(n+1)}P^{T})(n+1)$$
$$\det(A_{n+1}) = \det(A_{n} - (n+1)J)(n+1)\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots [1]$$
where J is a square matrix of only ones. Now,
$$-(A_{n} - (n+1)J)=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        n & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots &1 \\
        n-1 & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1 \\
        n-2&n-2&n-2&\cdots &1\\
        \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\ 
        1 & 1 & 1&\cdots& 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Inverse of such matrix is of the form:-
$$D = -(A_{n} - (n+1)J)^{-1}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
        -1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0&-1&2&\cdots &0\\
        \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\   
        0 & 0 & 0&\cdots& 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
By expanding along row 1 we could break det(D) in terms of determinant of a simpler matrix B i.e.$$\det(D_{n}) = \det(B_{n-1})-\det(B_{n-2})$$ where, $$B =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
        -1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0&-1&2&\cdots &0\\
        \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\   
        0 & 0 & 0&\cdots& 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
B follows the recursion formulla $$\det(B_{n}) = 2\det(B_{n-1})-\det(B_{n-2})$$ Base case $\det(B_{1}) = 2$, which gives $\det(B_{n}) = n+1. $

Hence, For such matrices D we have $\det(D_{n}) = 1$ $\space$     $\forall n\geq2$

Now from [1] we have $$\det(A_{n+1}) = (-1)^{n}(1)(n+1)$$