# Form matrix and calculate its determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I need help with this problem:

> For every $i,j \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is $d_{i,j} = \min\{i,j\}$. Calculate determinant of a matrix $[d_{i,j}]_{n_\times n}$.

Is it right that all the elements of this squared matrix are $1$, because of that $d_{i,j}=min\{i,j\}$? Then, value of determinant is $0$.

Comment: Why don't you just try a $2 \times 2$ example? What is $d_{2,2}$?

Comment: @ copper.hat But first I need to form a matrix. Is it right that all elements are $1$ by$d_{i,j}=min\{i,j\}$?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. There is a formula for $d_{i,j}$ which gives the $i,j$ entry.

Comment: @ copper.hat I am asking what are the elements of a matrix? And what is that formula?

Comment: The formula you gave above??? The $i,j$ entry is $\min(i,j)$.

Comment: Note that $d_{i,j}$ is *not* the minimum taken over all the possible values of $i$ and $j$ (which is $1$). The element $d_{i,j}$ is the $i$-th element of the $j$-th column (or the $j$-th element of the $i$-th row, as you prefer), and the minimum is taken *only* over those two indices. Thus, for example the $1$st element of every column is $1$, the $2$nd element of every column after the first is $2$, the $3$rd element of every column after the second is $3$, and so on (similarly for the rows).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluation of a specific determinant.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392738/evaluation-of-a-specific-determinant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matrix has determinant $1$, see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0209249.pdf). The matrix looks as follows
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \cr
1 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 \cr
1 & 2 & 3 &\cdots & 3 \cr
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: How to form that matrix if we only know the statement $d_{i,j}=min\{i,j\}$?

Comment: For example, $d_{2,3}=min(2,3)=2$, so the coefficient at place $(2,3)$ is equal to $2$.