# Does rotating a matrix change its determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

For a $2 \times 2$, it is easy to see the determinant only changes sign.

\begin{align*}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\ c & d
\end{array}
\right) \mapsto
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & a \\ d & b
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align*}

We can see that $\det(A) = -\det(A')$, where $A$ is the original matrix and $A'$ is the rotated matrix. Is this always the case for any $n \times n$ matrix?

Also, this would imply that $\det(A) = \det(A'')$.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by "rotating a matrix". Can you illustrate this with a larger (such as 4x4) matrix?

Comment: Rotating in the sense that if I drew the matrix on a piece of paper and turned the paper $90^\circ$ clockwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a $4\times 4$ matrix, rotating **preserves** the determinant.

In general rotating means transposing (determinant-preserving) followed by turning matrix upside down (multiplies determinant by $(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$).

Comment: What would multiplying by (-1)^(n/2)) mean if it was a 3x3?

Comment: There are floor brackets around the n/2 term, i.e. you round n/2 down if it’s not an integer. So for a 3x3 matrix you get a factor of -1.