# Find the determinant of an $n \times n$ square matrix $A$ whose entries are $a_{ij} = \max(i,j)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I figured the matrix would look like this,

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & 2 & 3 & \dots &  n \\
    2 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n \\
    3 & 3 & 3 & \dots & n \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
    n-1 & n-1 & n-1 & \dots & n \\
    n & n & n & \dots & n 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

but I do not know how to tackle it. Reduced row echelon row doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: I would compute the first few terms and feed it to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950310/determinant-of-matrix-with-a-ij-min-i-j/1950320#1950320): if you substract the $(i+1)$-th row to the $i$-th one, you will end up with a lower triangular matrix with all diagonal entries being $-1$ except $A_{nn} = n$, so $\det A = n(-1)^{n-1}$.